# Decision tree: how to manually setting a decision node

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to build a decision tree from scratch. This decision tree should take one email from a list and, based on some factors, assign a score.
For example: let's say that the email that I want to test is

email="I transferred **£20,000** into our **pension plan**, but the **money** never arrived. I had asked my **financial adviser** at Brewin Dolphin for the relevant **bank details** and he sent them by email."

Root node: I would like to consider as root node the variable "contain_number".If the email contains a number than assign -0.1 otherwise 0. These would be the two split. I would like to consider only binary split.

Child node: if the email contains a word in the list `['financial','bank', 'plan', 'money']`, then assign -0.1 otherwise 0.

and so on.
I know that there is a built-in classifier in Python:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # Import Decision Tree Classifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # Import train_test_split function
from sklearn import metrics #Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation
#split dataset in features and target variable
feature_cols = ['email', 'date', 'author', 'server']
X = pima[feature_cols] # Features
y = pima.label # Target variable

# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) # 70% training and 30% test

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

However I was wondering how to build a decisione tree based on some criteria.
Thank you for your time.

For clarifying what I would like to do
I have several columns like the following:

```
Sender         Server       Subject       Corpus       Date         % of xsuks@libero.it  libero    DEAL!!!     I want to propose a deal 29/10/2020   punctuation          % of Upper case
60                         40
```

I would like to build a decision tree which takes them into account based on some 'weight' that I give you to each variable.
For example:

- if the email does not contain any word in a spam_list, then assign 0;
- if the email contains words in a spam list, then assign -0.1 per each word included in the spam list;
- if Sender includes misspelled bad words, then assign -0.1;
- if Sender does not include misspelled bad words, then assign 0;
- if the percentage of punctuation is > 50%, then assign -0.1; otherwise 0;
  ...

I have also a labelled column which includes labels that I assigned manually for automatically build a Decision Tree in Python (using the code I shown above); however I do not know how to include all the fields of my interest because some of them are categorical (like senders, subject and corpus; others are numerical, like %).
At the end, I would like to compare the results that I get from my own decision tree for scoring to that got from a classifier in Python.
For checking the accuracy, I would use confusion matrix or ROC.

This is pretty much what I would like to achieve.

Comment: It would be nice to explain why you want to do this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to build this decision tree by implementing step by step an algorithm which can allow me to assign scores to quantify how an email can be considered  'spam' , for example, looking at keywords, server, punctuation, sender, ... . Maybe this can be done using the Decision Tree classifier in Python (sklearn), but I was wondering how I should do if I wanted to build a decision tree from scratch, looking at the root node, then at the other decision nodes

Comment: First of all, if you just want to compare your human intuition of what would be an efficient decision tree to classify spam email versus a machine learning algorithm, it is highly likely that you will just end up finding out that the ML algorithm will do a much better job that you are able to do. This is because we humans are not good enough at solving multidimensional abstract problems directly, unless we define a mathematical model that is designed to do exactly that.

Comment: Second, if you want to learn how to implement decision trees, I propose to start with a tutorial on binary trees and try to augment it with data that will allow you to store in each node the variable id that you are spliting and the information of the splitting point. It will be different how to do that depending on the kind of the variable, that is, numerical vs categorical.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, what I would like to do is not just assign a binary variable (spam not spam) but quantify how much 'spam information' an email includes. I do not know how I could do that using ML algorithm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223860/discussion-between-sns-and-math).